# Pinout of iPhone 4/4S rear camera connector?

Tags: camera, iphone, pinout

Has anyone come across the pinout of an iPhone 4/4S rear camera module connector?

Comment: Why do you need the pinout?

Comment: I wanted to use the camera for a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these two schematics one for the [iPhone 4S] and the other for [iPhone 4]. Both connectors can be seen on the board level on the third page. They are designated as J6. The connector pinout can be found on page 19 of each schematic. It seems that the 4S got 6 more pins in the connector. But it does not specify whats the model number. The only info is BB4-PA26-3A and BB4-PA32-3A which I can see how it calls out the 26/32 regular pins, and 4 power pins (power for the LED driver i guess), and I guess it calls out for 3amp specs on the pins. Need to find out the pitch...

Comment: Board-to-Board 0.4mm pitch, P= plug (S or R for female), A = ?, 26/32 = number of conductors, 3 = Plating type/option, A=?

Comment: Oh wow, that is a pretty cool collection of schematics

Comment: Molex [offers](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=slimstack_mm016_pitch&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=mobile_industry_processor_interface_mipi#related) MIPI connectors with 26 pins. Do you think it will mate? If so, what would be the mated height?

Comment: The links are dead.

Comment: Its weird how that site manage its URLs. The folder won't link well. It says that "**The directory ./downloads/Apple/Service Manuals / does not exist.**", But the text is light on a light background. So its hard to read it. If you will highlight the light box on the left you will see a "**Continue**" hyperlink. Press on that - and it will take you to a folder with bunch of DPFs. Navigate through the folders to **Apple >  Service Manuals & Schematics  0 days old > iPhone_4s** or **iPhone_4**

Comment: All those PDFs are confidential and protected materials. I can understand why that site would try to obscure them, it is blatantly illegal to distribute them.